# Excel formula for string split into specific cell

Tags: excel, string, text, formula

[image]
any formula that works on both excel and googles sheet for splitting text to their column.

I want a formula that split text from string to specific column.

Comment: Looks like you are using GS in your screenshot. Please choose either Excel or GS as your app.

Answer (score 1):

For Excel ms365, try:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1:H1,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A2,": ","|",1)),2,0),"")
```

Or, if you are not willing to remove the needless colon's and spaces in your data in the 1st row:

[image]

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(B1:H1,":",)),TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A2,": ","|",1)),2,0),"")
```

---

I suppose the GS equivalent for the 1st option would be:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1:H1,TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A2,"|")),":")),2,0),""))
```

But GS is not my forte.

Answer (score 1):

You may ***try*** this as well in **Excel** for **MS365**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B3` --> Needs to drag right.

```
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER($A3&" | ",B$1,,,,"")," | ",,,,"")
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `B5` --> It will spill.

```
=DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE(0,A5,LAMBDA(x,y,
VSTACK(x,BYCOL(B1:I1,LAMBDA(z,TEXTBEFORE(
TEXTAFTER(y&" | ",z,,,,"")," | ",,,,"")))))),""),1)
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell `B7` --> Will spill right but needs to drag down for below cells.

```
=BYCOL(B1:I1,LAMBDA(x,TEXTBEFORE(
TEXTAFTER($A7&" | ",x,,,,"")," | ",,,,"")))
```